# Using ifequal in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm sure there is something silly I'm missing here, but I'm trying to use ifequal to evaluate a template variable.

Here's my model:

```
USER_TYPES = (
('instructor', 'Instructor'),
('student', 'Student'),
)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=USER_TYPES, max_length=12
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        unique=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.type)
```

...and I'm using this in the template:

```
{% ifequal user.userprofile_set.get student %}
You're a student! 
{% endifequal %}
```

When I simply print out {{ user.userprofile_set.get }} I get:

```
student
```

Not sure what I'm missing - any help is appreciated!

Comment: `ifequal` is deprecated in recent django versions, just use `if a == b`. Put `"` around `student`, and be sure to try that on the django shell first: `user.userprofile_set.get() == 'student'`

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I ended up using `{% if user.userprofile_set.get.type == "student" %}` and it worked great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ifequal is deprecated... but I think that this works:

```
{% ifequal user.userprofile_set.get.type "student" %}
    You're a student! 
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: Just wanted to post the same. If you just use `student` Django will "think" its a template variable. Since you compare against a string this will of course not work.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I ended up using `{% if user.userprofile_set.get.type == "student" %}` and it worked great!  Thanks!