# If statment doesn't work in a template file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I have a weird situation with if statement in Django. It seems that django doesn't see it and I don't know why

my template file:

```
            <div class="article-intro">
                <p>{{ article.jezyk }} </p>
                {% if article.jezyk = 'EN' %}   
                      {% for sala in sala %}
                                     <div>{{ sala }}</div>
                      {%endfor %}                     
                {% endif %}       
            </div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

As we see on the picture tag:

```
{{ article.jezyk }}
```

returns a value 'EN'

Why then "if statment"  doesn't work? Is there any explanation?

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from articles.models import Article
from sale.models import Sala
from godzina.models import Godzina
from jezyk.models import Jezyk


def articles(request):
    return render_to_response('articles.html',{'articles' : Article.objects.all(),'godzina': Godzina.objects.all(),'sala': Sala.objects.order_by('jezyk') })
```

Comment: Because it's  `{% if article.jezyk == 'EN' %}` - notice the `==`... The docs say: *if tags may also use the operators ==, !=, <, >, <=, >= and in which work as follows:* - ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

Answer (score 2):

Once again you have not provided the information necessary to answer your question, ie the models. However we know from your previous questions that Article.jezyk is a ForeignKey. When you output a FK field in the template, it will print the result of the unicode method, but that doesn't mean they are actually equal. You need to compare the field itself, for example:

```
{% if article.jezyk.language = 'EN' %}
```

or whatever the field is on the Jezyk model that contains the language code.

Answer (score 1):

1. try this `ifequal` :

e.g

```
{% ifequal article.jezyk 'EN' %}
  <!-- Ur code -->

{% endifequal %}
```

2. use `==` operator

e.g.

```
{% if somevar == "x" %}
  This appears if variable somevar equals the string "x"
{% endif %}
```

Documentation: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/)

3. Use other variable name in for loop. Same `sala` variable is used for iterator.

e.g.:

```
{% for i in sala %}
      <div>{{ i }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733651/using-ifequal-in-django#comment-15571436